# Gameobject not destroying when image target lost vuforia- Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Im developing an AR application with vuforia and unity for hololens . I have some canvas components which have to be destroyed when image target is lost . Im using defaulttrackableeventhandler to destroy those object with gameobject.setactive(false); in tracking lost function. The very same app works well with android phone but not with hololens
When built for UWP , the gameobject is not destroying even in play mode. Its destroying twice and stays static on the third time and when viewed in hololens , the canvas is not even disabling . Any fix for this ?

Comment: Any error/warning messages? Exceptions? Also please make clear: Do you `Destroy` or just `disable` the object?

Comment: Fixed it man. Turns out it was because of extended tracking .

Comment: @SamSundar Extended tracking was switched on where and how did you switch it off?  I think others will run into this issue but may not be clear how to fix/turn off extended tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it .. 
Turns out 
**`extended tracking`** was switched on by default , had to turn this off .